# Finding the eigenvectors of a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hi how do I find the eigenvector of the eigenvalue=8 for the matrix below.

What I've done so far is:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Rj8.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hkk1.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuUpH.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dividing the last two rows by $(\pm)\,6$, you seem to replace $\tfrac{12}{6}$ by $1$ instead of $2$. It should be:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 7 \\
0 & 1 & \color{red}{2} \\
0 & 1 & \color{red}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Now $R_3 \to R_3-R_2$ and $R_1 \to R_1-4R_2$ to get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
And you have $x=z$ and $y=-2z$; so the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda=8$ is any non-zero multiple of $(1,-2,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to work directly from the definition: 
Saying that 8 is an eigenvalue for this matrix means that there exist a non-zero vector, $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}$, such that
$\begin{pmatrix}3 & - 2 & 1 \\ -2 & 6 & -2 \\ 1 & -2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}3x- 2y+ z \\ -2x+ 6y- 2z \\ x- 2y+ 3z\end{pmatrix}= 8\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}8x \\ 8y \\ 8z\end{pmatrix}$.

That is equivalent to the three equations 3x- 2y+ z= 8x, -2x+ 6y- 2z= 8y, x- 2y+ 3z= 8z, which reduce to the homogeneous equations -5x- 2y+ z= 0, -2x- 2y- 2z= 0, and x- 2y- 5z= 0.  The second equation is equivalent to x+ y+ z= 0 or z= -x- y.  Putting that into the first and third equations, -5x- 2y- x- y= -6x- 3y= 0 and x- 2y+ 5x+ 5y= 6x+ 3y= 0.  Those both reduce to y= -2x and then z= -x- y= -x+ 2x= x.  For any non-zero x, $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ -2x \\ x\end{pmatrix}= x\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 8.